# SMS auto-verify not working inside fragment for verifying phone number using firebase-auth

Tags: android, firebase, sms, firebase-authentication, telephony

I have recently moved my app from Digits to Firebase phone number authentication.
Everything works except the sdk cant auto verify incoming SMS.
I am calling the below code from a fragment:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            getActivity(),               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```

It works fine if the user enters the verification code manually in the Edittext I have setup but never auto detects.

I think it is due to code being placed inside a fragment instead of activity.

Comment: It should not be related to Fragment / Activity. The auto-retrieval is done in Google Play services. Right now, auto-retrieval works for SMS delivered via GSM network. Virtual phone numbers are not supported. Also, at this moment, Firebase limits the capability of SMS auto-retrieval to certain countries / carriers and the requirement will be loosened in releases later this year (no SDK update required).

Comment: thank you for your inputs.for now I have implemented a custom implementaion of OTP detection and submit the OTP programatically(working flawlessly) until auto detection starts working widely.

Comment: Just wait till end of Aug / early Sep and auto-retrieval will work for all carriers. And you can then get rid of the read sms runtime permission.